# Clone and resize NTFS GPT partition?

Tags: ntfs, clone, vmware-converter, gparted, gpt

I have a ntfs partition, GPT, of 5.6 TB containing only 200 GB of data, that I need to fit onto a 1 TB partition (of a vmware ESXi guest).
Vmware converter does not support GPT.
Acronis disk director does not support GPT.
As I am not very familiar with the Windows operating system, I would rather not copy over "network shares", ftp or similar - I foresee too many problems with that. (correct me if Im wrong!).
I could dd/parted/gzip the raw partition, but unpacking it to a smaller partition might cause problems. Anyone know if problems like that could be resolved by running CHKDSK or similar?

What wuld you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd mount the filesystem and copy it at a file level rather than trying to disk image it. I suspect it'll end up being faster for you and you won't have to contend with disk partitioning issues.

The built-in (at least in Windows Vista and newer) `robocopy` command can copy all the files, metadata, and ACLs pretty easily.

You could use a Linux distro with GPT support and the ntfsprogs `ntfsclone` to close the filesytem.

I wouldn't copy the filesystem raw at a block level, though. I'd have a hard time trusting it after doing that.

Comment: I have a robocopy /MIR running, not sure if that actually preserves ACLs or not. I think I will have to initiate the iscsi luns directly to the server and robocopy locally (between DAS and SAN luns), rather than over samba..

Comment: Seems ACLs are not preserved by default (COPY:DAT), so '/MIR COPY:DATSO' are the options to use.